# Polynomial Division algorithm using DFT

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, recursive-algorithms, fourier-transform

I am given to polynomials $p$ and $q$ of size $n-1$and $m-1$ where $n\geq m$. I also have the division algorithm below:

```
1. Let n' be the smallest power of 2 greater than n − 1.
2. Use the FFT to compute y = DFTn'(p), and z = DFTn'(q).
3. Compute the n-dimensional vector {y0/z0, y1/z1, . . . , yn0/zn0}.
4. Compute a = DFT^-1 {y0/z0, y1/z1, . . . , yn0/zn0}),
and return this as the coefficient vector for p(x)/q(x)
```

I have to find the cases when this will reconstruct $p(x)/q(x)$ succesfully both when $p(x)/q(x)$ can be represented by a polynomial and when it is an infinite series.

I have no clear idea of how to go about solving this and any help would be appreciated. I've had ideas of maybe computing the FFT and inverse DFT but can't see how I would reach my conclusion

Comment: The convolution which happens to the polynomial coefficients under a multiplication of polynomials is not a circular convolution, but that is what happens when you do multiplication in the Fourier domain so what you may need to do is ensure you won't get any wrap-around. This could probably be solved by ensuring you have padded with enough 0s.

Answer (score -1):

There is division with reminder algorithm using DFT: http://www.diag.uniroma1.it/sankowski/lecture4.pdf

Comment: While the link might provide a solution, it would be great if you can summarize the main concept or idea.

Comment: The main idea is combination of Barrett reduction (in polynomial form) and DFT fast multiplication: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrett_reduction 
Working time of the algorithm is O(n*log(n))